# Constructing a ring F_2(u)/<u^2=0> in GAP

Tags: ring-theory, gap

I need to construct the following ring in GAP:

$$F_2(u) / \langle u^2=0 \rangle =\{ \; a+bu \; | \; a,b \in F_2 \; \}=\{0,1,u,1+u\}$$.

I tried using the commands `PolynomialRing` and `PolynomialReduction`, however I couldn't get it to work.  This is what I tried and it didn't work:

```
R:=PolynomialRing(GF(2),["u"]);
u:=Indeterminant(GF(2),"u");
R1:=PolynomialReduction(R,[u^2],MonomialTotalDegreeLess);
```

Does anyone know how to construct this ring in GAP?

Thanking you in advance!

Comment: Welcome to MSE! :) I've edited the question to show how to format LaTeX and code.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to form a quotient:

```
gap> R:=PolynomialRing(GF(2),"u");AssignGeneratorVariables(R);
GF(2)[u]
gap>  I:=Ideal(R,[u^2]);
<two-sided ideal in GF(2)[u], (1 generators)>
gap> A:=R/I;
<ring GF(2),(1),(u)>
gap> Filtered(Elements(A),IsUnit);
[ (1), (1)+(u) ]
```

(The `PolynomialReduction` command you use would take the remainder when dividing by an ideal given by a Gröbner basis.)

Generically (if you cannot describe the ring easily as quotient of a polynomial ring over a field), there is `RingBystructureConstants` as well as a library of small rings given by `SmallRing`.